# java - Getting current date and time based on the locale (country)

Tags: java, date, time, locale, country

I would like to fetch the current date / time based on the locale. If I pass locale object, I need to get the relevant date / time of the country.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 you have `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`

So you can do the same as @Babar said:

Get a zone id

`ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels");`

And then get date and time

`ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);`

Comment: What happens when zone (for example  `"Europe/Zurich"`) have daylight saving? Will hour change automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        String[] timeZoneIDList = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        //List of Time Zones
        for(String timeZoneID:timeZoneIDList){
            System.out.println(timeZoneID);
        }
        //What time is it in Fiji
        Calendar fijiCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Fiji"));
        System.out.println("Time in Fiji->"+fijiCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+fijiCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }
```

Comment: How to know the country name from where the user is accessing ?

Comment: @Sriram dantuch has already answered one solution. So another option is just ask the user to select the appropriate timezone for themselves if they do not want the default timezone offer by the application using host-name.

Comment: This way, 'm unable to get the Date. Giving a wrong value. Any alternative ?

Comment: Yes `.getTime()` will not give you the relevant Date object with the above approach. But you can use `.get(Calendar.HOUR)`, `.get(Calendar.MONTH)` and so on to get a Date in string format.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) then following should work. (Don't have the compiler at hand)

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Winnipeg");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(tz);
```

You can get the Timezone Ids [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). Please check the link given by dantuch too.